# How to convert index array to associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array:10 [
       1 => "1. What is the first question?"
       2 => "A. First answer"
       3 => "B. Second answer"
       4 => "C. Third answer"
       5 => "D. Forth answer"
       6 => "ANSWER: A"
       7 => "2. What is the second question? This question is of multiple lines and it can 
             go into 2 or 3 or 4 lines, but make sure you import it correctly."
       8 => "A. Yes, I got it"
       9 => "B. No, I can’t"
       10 => "ANSWER: A"
   ]
```

and I want to achieve array like this:

```
array:2[
      'questions' => [
           0 => [
             'question_text' => '1. What is the first question?',
             'options' => [
                            0 => 'A. First answer',
                            1 => 'B. Second answer',
                            2 => 'C. Third answer',
                            3 => 'D. Forth answer'
                           ],
             'answer' => 'ANSWER: A'
             ],
         1 => [
             'question_text' => '2. What is the second question? This question is of 
                                  multiple lines and it can go into 2 or 3 or 4 lines, but 
                                  make sure you import it correctly."',
             'options' => [
                            0 => 'A. Yes, I got it',
                            1 => 'B. No, I can’t',

                           ],
             'answer' => 'ANSWER: A'
             ],
       ]
 ]
```

I want to convert this indexing array to multidimensional array. How can I convert this array?

Comment: I have no idea about how you get this array, but to transform it you're gonna end up writing spaghetti code that will only work for one specific set of data and you'll have to add more and more logic to handle all cases. I'd suggest re-working the way the array is generated instead of transforming the array afterwards.

Comment: Bascially , my main functionality is .Docx  file insert in database. and I have this type of .DOcx File. so I am converting Docx File to array. @N

Comment: @scode2704 We can add a specific solution for your input only If your array format changes in any case, Then the solution wont work

Comment: Please post your attempted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be this big spaghetti code, even if it doesn't fit in two lines:

```
$array = [
       1 => "1. What is the first question?",
       2 => "A. First answer",
       3 => "B. Second answer",
       4 => "C. Third answer",
       5 => "D. Forth answer",
       6 => "ANSWER: A",
       7 => "2. What is the second question? This question is of multiple lines and it can 
             go into 2 or 3 or 4 lines, but make sure you import it correctly.",
       8 => "A. Yes, I got it",
       9 => "B. No, I can’t",
       10 => "ANSWER: A",
   ];

$questionIndex=-1;
$target_array = ['questions' => []];
foreach ($array as $entry) {
    if (strpos($entry, ".")!==false) {
      list ($left,$right) = explode (".",$entry);
      if (is_numeric(trim($left))) 
        $target_array['questions'][++$questionIndex] = ['question_text' => $entry, 'options' => [], 'answer' => ''];
      else
        $target_array['questions'][$questionIndex]['options'][] = $entry;
    } else {
      $target_array['questions'][$questionIndex]['answer'] = $entry;
    }
}
var_dump ($target_array);
```

results in:

```
array(1) {
  ["questions"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["question_text"]=>
      string(30) "1. What is the first question?"
      ["options"]=>
      array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(15) "A. First answer"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "B. Second answer"
        [2]=>
        string(15) "C. Third answer"
        [3]=>
        string(15) "D. Forth answer"
      }
      ["answer"]=>
      string(9) "ANSWER: A"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["question_text"]=>
      string(158) "2. What is the second question? This question is of multiple lines and it can 
             go into 2 or 3 or 4 lines, but make sure you import it correctly."
      ["options"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(16) "A. Yes, I got it"
        [1]=>
        string(16) "B. No, I can’t"
      }
      ["answer"]=>
      string(9) "ANSWER: A"
    }
  }
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/081dbbdd66c160f303d9a99bbd01806a7adf7708

nevertheless it is of course a very special task and I agree with the previous speaker that the array is unusually specified. But if that's the case, you have to live with the guidelines ...